# Particle system

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I am trying to Using Particle system From the below link 
https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids

```
                ParticleSystem ps = new ParticleSystem(holder.itemView.getContext(), 50, R.drawable.emoji_1f358, 1000);
                ps.setSpeedRange(0.1f, 0.25f);
                ps.setScaleRange(0.7f, 1.3f);
                ps.setSpeedRange(0.1f, 0.25f);
                ps.setAcceleration(0.0001f, 90);
                ps.setRotationSpeedRange(90, 180);
                ps.setFadeOut(200, new AccelerateInterpolator());
                ps.emit(v, 100)
```

I am Trying to Use it in a MyAdapter File in the below function :-

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolderCHAT holder, final int position) {
}
```

This is Giving me an Build error as Below :-

> Error:(1824, 41) error: no suitable constructor found for
>   ParticleSystem(Context,int,int,int) constructor
>   ParticleSystem.ParticleSystem(ViewGroup,int,Drawable,long) is not
>   applicable (argument mismatch; Context cannot be converted to
>   ViewGroup) constructor
>   ParticleSystem.ParticleSystem(Activity,int,int,long) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; Context cannot be converted to Activity)
>   constructor ParticleSystem.ParticleSystem(Activity,int,Drawable,long)
>   is not applicable (argument mismatch; Context cannot be converted to
>   Activity) constructor
>   ParticleSystem.ParticleSystem(Activity,int,Bitmap,long) is not
>   applicable (argument mismatch; Context cannot be converted to
>   Activity) constructor
>   ParticleSystem.ParticleSystem(Activity,int,AnimationDrawable,long) is
>   not applicable (argument mismatch; Context cannot be converted to
>   Activity)

Here is my code for adapter :

```
public class MyAdapterCHAT extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolderCHAT>  {

    Context c;
    Activity activity;
    int click=0;
    int img_pos;
    boolean isPlaying=false;
    static MediaPlayer mp;
    int curr_pos;
     ViewGroup vg;
    CountDownTimer cT;
    int total;
    String DBname;
    //private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;

    ArrayList<String> path;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    String react;
    ArrayList<String> pagerListItems;
    int progress=0;
    ArrayList<DATA_CONTACT_CHAT> data_contact,filterlist22;
  //  private final ItemClickListener listener;

    public MyAdapterCHAT(Context c, ArrayList<DATA_CONTACT_CHAT> data_contact) {
        this.c = c;
        this.data_contact = data_contact;
        this.filterlist22=data_contact;
       // this.listener=listener;
    }


    @Override
    public MyHolderCHAT onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

       View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chatinputlayout,parent,false);

        MyHolderCHAT myHolderCHAT=new MyHolderCHAT(view);

        //this.vg=parent;

        return myHolderCHAT;
    }


 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolderCHAT holder, final int position) {
        //BIND DATA

holder.hi5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(holder.counter_hi5.getText().toString().contains("remaining:"))
                {
                    if (data_contact.get(position).getSender_name().equals(data_contact.get(position).getCurrent_user())) {

                        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) holder.itemView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibe.vibrate(100);
                        Toast.makeText(c, " \uD83C\uDFFB Ohh..Wait for " + data_contact.get(position).getSecond_user() + " To Hi5 You..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        cT.cancel();
                        holder.counter_hi5.setText(" \uD83D\uDE00 You got a High Five from " + data_contact.get(position).getSecond_user());

                   ParticleSystem ps = new ParticleSystem(holder.itemView.getContext(), 50, R.drawable.emoji_1f358, 1000);
                    ps.setSpeedRange(0.1f, 0.25f);
                   ps.setScaleRange(0.7f, 1.3f);
                    ps.setSpeedRange(0.1f, 0.25f);
                   ps.setAcceleration(0.0001f, 90);
                   ps.setRotationSpeedRange(90, 180);
                    ps.setFadeOut(200, new AccelerateInterpolator());
                    ps.emit(v, 100);

                    }
                }
                else {

                }
            }
        });



}
```

Comment: Seems like `ParticleSystem` doesn't take a `Context`. It takes either an `Activity` or a `ViewGroup` as the first argument in its constructor call. Do you have a `ViewGroup` in your `ViewHolder` for it?

Comment: What should i Input then...Kindly help

Comment: Do you have a `ViewGroup` in your `ViewHolder` for it?

Comment: i will just put my code in...pls wait..

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace is giving exactly what's happening. There is not constructor for parameters you are passing.

You can try another method to instantiate it.

For example: `new ParticleSystem(ViewGroup, int, Drawable , long)`

So,

```
Context ctx = holder.itemView.getContext()
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) holder.itemView.getParent();
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.emoji_1f358);
ParticleSystem ps = new ParticleSystem(vg, 50, drawable, 1000L);
ps.setSpeedRange(0.1f, 0.25f);
ps.setScaleRange(0.7f, 1.3f);
ps.setSpeedRange(0.1f, 0.25f);
ps.setAcceleration(0.0001f, 90);
ps.setRotationSpeedRange(90, 180);
ps.setFadeOut(200, new AccelerateInterpolator());
ps.emit(v, 100)
```

Comment: ERROR >>> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference at